# Computing eigenvectors given shrinkage eigenvalues

Tags: r, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I used the function *linshrink* of the *nlshrink* package to have a shrinkage estimation of the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix **M**. Unfortunately the function does not return the eigenvectors, which I also need. How can I manually compute them? I thought about applying the definition and use (**M** − λ**I**)**x** = **0** for every eigenvalue λ, but I'm not sure how to properly do it, since computing the matrix **A** = **M** − λ**I** and using it as an input in `solve(A,b)` with `b=rep(0,nrow(M))` obviously returns a vector of zero. Can anybody help me? Here are a few lines to provide a working example:

```
library(nlshrink)
M <- matrix(1:16,4)
M[lower.tri(M)] = t(M)[lower.tri(M)]
M <- M/16.1
shrinkval <- linshrink(M)  #eigenvalues
```

Comment: @李哲源 The package should just apply the technique used in the very famous Ledoit and Wolf (2004) paper to estimate the covariance matrix. But I need the eigenvalues and eigenvectors estimated in this way for a different application. Anyway, even if I use the standard eigen function to get the eigenvalues and then try to manually compute the eigenvectors, I have the same problem.

Comment: @李哲源Still, you have a point, in my application I have a symmetric matrix. I'll edit my question, thanks for making me notice that.